# Limit message length in Log4J

Tags: log4j

I'm working on an application that uses Log4J for logging. Occasionally, the application creates log messages that are *very* long, > 10000 characters. This causes performance problems when the log is displayed in a Console window in Eclipse.

I want to limit the maximum message length, truncating long messages to the maximum length. How can I do that with Log4J?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) with a ConversionPattern that has a 'maximum width' format modifier on the message conversion character.

Example:

```
%r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %.10000m%n
```

limits message size to 10000 characters.

Comment: FYI, this removes the first 10000 char not after 10000

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a maximum width, that is removing the last characters and not the first (like i did) here is an example:

```
%r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %-0.-10000m%n
```

limits the message size to 10000 characters and removes everything on the end that is longer.

source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-926